# cast LAError EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS8

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, touch-id

In code

```
var error: NSError?
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) == false, let error = error {
  let error =  error as? LAError else {
     return .failure
  }
}
```

I have had crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS only on iPhone 5 iOS8 in line

```
let error =  error as? LAError else
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to fix it:

```
var error: NSError?
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) == false, let error = error {
  let error = LAError(_nsError: error)
}
```